# Squid периодически не пускает на сайт

Tags: squid

squid3 регулярно "сам" не пускает на один конкретный сайт. То есть некоторое время сайт открывается, а потом на некоторое время загрузка сайта зависает на несколько минут и в конце в браузере появляется сообщение о том что запрашиваемый url не может быть доставлен. Какие есть предположения по поводу решения данной проблемы?

P.S. Конфиг минимальный:

```
http_port 192.168.0.1:3128 transparentcache_mem 87040cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3/cache 20000 16 256acl allowed_hosts src 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255acl allow_ports port 80acl allow_ports port 21 23 122 70 210 110 25 5190acl SSL_ports port 443 563 910 8443 4500acl CONNECT method CONNECThttp_access deny !allow_portshttp_access deny CONNECT !SSL_portshttp_access allow localhosthttp_access allow allow_portshttp_access allow SSL_portshttp_access deny all
```

Заметил, что "зависание" происходит когда на данный сайт заходит один конкретный пользователь, тогда для остальных сайт оказывается недоступен. У него макбук, может как-то это влиять на проблему?

Comment: а мимо сквида сайт открывается в это время? как часто возникает проблема?возможно ли запустить пинги в сторону сайта?точно ли все остальные сайты открывются нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Что используется помимо squid`a? (squidguard может быть?), ну и сообственно конфиг сквида озвучить, так отвечать тыкать пальцем в небо.

Comment: у меня аналогичная проблема... причём только в отношении HTTPS